# Projection as Affine Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, projection

$S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$ is projected onto some of its coordinates: $$T = \{x_1 \in \mathbb{R}^m | \ (x_1,x_2)\in S \text{ for some } x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n \}. $$

Can I show this projection as an **affine map**?

Comment: This does not make sense. Where is the map? Do you want to show that the set $T$ is affine (for affine $S$)?

Comment: tbh I just want to show that if $S$ is a convex set, then $T$ is. I know projection on coordinates of a convex set gives another convex set. I want to prove this inequality by the fact that affine maps present convexity..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This projection is a linear map of the type
$$
F(x_1,x_2) = x_1.
$$
Then $T = F(S)$ is convex if $S$ is convex.